# flot ,and mysql jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a problem using flot to plot data from a database.
using `json_encode` in php I have tried to get the plot data but I have been unsuccessful.
Below is my code, kindly assist

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>`enter code here`
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Flot Examples</title>
    <link href="./flot/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./flot/jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>

 </head>
    <body>

    <h1>Database Plotting</h1>

    <div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>

<?php

    $server = "localhost";
    $user="user";
    $password="password"; 
    $database = "database";

    $connection = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password);
    $db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection);

    $query = "SELECT x_value, y_value FROM table";
    $result = mysql_query($query);  

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $dataset1[] = array($row['x_value'],$row['y_value']);
    }

?>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var dataset1 = <?php echo json_encode($dataset1,); ?>;

    $.plot($("#placeholder"),[dataset1] );
});
</script>

 </body>
</html>
```

The ouput from the `json-encode dataset1` is thus the following `[["1380111342","0"],["1380111679","0"],["1380112099","20"],["1380112109","300"],["1380112114","40"],["1380112120","56"],["1380112127","36"],["1380112132","40"],["1380112138","78"]]`

Comment: Please dont use `mysql_*` because it is depreciated. use `PDO` or `mysqli_*`

Answer (score 0):

Try change this line:

```
$.plot($("#placeholder"), [dataset1] );
```

To that:

```
$.plot($("#placeholder"), [JSON.parse(dataset1)]);
```

Comment: I did use [JSON.parse(dataset1)]but still am not able to plot .Any help is urgently needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataset1 = <?php echo json_encode($dataset1,); ?>;
```

Lose the comma after "$dataset1" and the semi-colon at the end.

This should work just fine:

```
var dataset1 = <?php echo json_encode($dataset1); ?>
```